# Problems to create custom attributes xmlns:android="schemas.android" Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, android, xml, xaml, xamarin.android

I'm new in Xamarin Studio, I'm trying to create a custom attribute in XAML, in a cross plataform solution, I´m using the `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` reference, but when I use the prefix `android:text="Hello world"`, and I run the solution it show me an error of "property 'text' was not found" at this line of code.

**XAML Code:**

```
<ContentPage.Content>

    <Label Text="Hellow Word"
            android:textStyle="Italic">         </Label>

</ContentPage.Content > </ContentPage>
```

**Manifest Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0" 
          package="app.monodroid">  
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />     
        <application android:label="Push_Money_N">
        </application> 
    </manifest>
```

**Error:**
[image]

Thanks for any help, I have been trying for many days to solve this problem. I'm very new to Xamarin Studio, and I've worked with Android Studio before and in it I can use this custom attribute. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry the atribute that I´m trying to use is android:textStyle, not android:text